# How to set up autoreload with Flask+uWSGI?

Tags: flask, uwsgi, werkzeug

I am looking for something like [uWSGI + django autoreload mode](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/TipsAndTricks) for Flask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using supervisord as a manager for your Uwsgi app. It also has a watch function that auto-reloads a process when a file or folder has been "touched"/modified.

You will find a nice tutorial here: [Flask+NginX+Uwsgi+Supervisord](https://web.archive.org/web/20120924045956/http://www.readncode.com:80/blog/Deploying-Flask-with-nginx-uWSGI-and-Supervisor/)

Comment: The link is no longer available

Comment: archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20120924045956/http://www.readncode.com:80/blog/Deploying-Flask-with-nginx-uWSGI-and-Supervisor/

Comment: suspicious link?

Answer (score 64):

I am running uwsgi version 1.9.5 and the option

```
uwsgi --py-autoreload 1
```

works great

Comment: Using uwsgi emperor mode, works neither for emperor process launch nor individual app ini config. Former gives "unknown option", latter gives nothing. Either way, process has to be restarted for changes to be noticed...

Comment: How do I run uwsgi --py-autoreload 1

Comment: realpath() of --py-autoreload=1 failed: No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3651]

Answer (score 36):

If you're configuring `uwsgi` with command arguments, pass `--py-autoreload=1`:

```
uwsgi --py-autoreload=1
```

If you're using a `.ini` file to configure `uwsgi` and using `uwsgi --ini`, add the following to your `.ini` file:

```
py-autoreload = 1
```

Comment: Documentation: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html and https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=py-autoreload#py-auto-reload

Answer (score 14):

For development environment you can try using 
--python-autoreload  uwsgi's parameter.
Looking at the source code it may work only in threaded mode (--enable-threads).

Comment: This one worked for me. Adding `python-autoreload = 1` to my `uwsgi.ini` file gets it to reload! Thanks!

Comment: Using uwsgi emperor mode - this worked by adding to app's ini. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the values `1` and `true` are *not* interchangeable here. Only `1` works for me.

Comment: @kungphu that's because the value it is expecting is the number of seconds to wait scan for changes.  A value of 2 would tell uwsgi to scan every 2 seconds.

Comment: @AdamRitter Thanks for that explanation; did it come from reading the source? The only reference I'm seeing to that behavior is [in a snippet](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Snippets.html?highlight=autoreload#python-auto-reloading-development-only); the [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Snippets.html?highlight=autoreload#python-auto-reloading-development-only) suggests it's a flag rather than an interval.

Comment: @kungphu read the documentation again, it says when enabled it starts a thread up that scans for changes.  The value you set it at is the interval in which it does the scans.

Comment: @AdamRitter I accidentally linked the snippet twice. The *snippet* says that for `py-autoreload`; the documentation does not. Also, that is not the attribute which was asked about, which is `python-autoreload`. There are [several options in the actual doc](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#py-auto-reload) that seem to be the same, including these two, though they're not marked as aliases. Which is a bit confusing, and in any case, the description is not clear regarding that behavior. I'd submit a patch to the doc if I knew for a fact what was actually going on.

Answer (score 6):

The auto-reloading functionality of development-mode Flask is actually provided by the underlying Werkzeug library. The relevant code is in `werkzeug/serving.py` -- it's worth taking a look at. But basically, the main application spawns the WSGI server as a subprocess that stats every active `.py` file once per second, looking for changes. If it sees any, the subprocess exits, and the parent process starts it back up again -- in effect reloading the chages.

There's no reason you couldn't implement a similar technique at the layer of uWSGI. If you don't want to use a stat loop, you can try using underlying OS file-watch commands. Apparently (according to Werkzeug's code), [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) is buggy, but perhaps [Watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/) works? Try a few things out and see what happens.

**Edit:**

In response to the comment, I think this would be pretty easy to reimplement. Building on the example provided from your link, along with the code from `werkzeug/serving.py`:

```
""" NOTE: _iter_module_files() and check_for_modifications() are both
    copied from Werkzeug code. Include appropriate attribution if
    actually used in a project. """
import uwsgi
from uwsgidecorators import timer

import sys
import os

def _iter_module_files():
    for module in sys.modules.values():
        filename = getattr(module, '__file__', None)
        if filename:
            old = None
            while not os.path.isfile(filename):
                old = filename
                filename = os.path.dirname(filename)
                if filename == old:
                    break
            else:
                if filename[-4:] in ('.pyc', '.pyo'):
                    filename = filename[:-1]
                yield filename

@timer(3)
def check_for_modifications():
    # Function-static variable... you could make this global, or whatever
    mtimes = check_for_modifications.mtimes
    for filename in _iter_module_files():
        try:
            mtime = os.stat(filename).st_mtime
        except OSError:
            continue

        old_time = mtimes.get(filename)
        if old_time is None:
            mtimes[filename] = mtime
            continue
        elif mtime > old_time:
            uwsgi.reload()
            return

check_for_modifications.mtimes = {} # init static
```

It's untested, but should work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I had looked a bit through werkzeug.serving, but hoped I could avoid getting my hands dirty, by asking for a quick solution... maybe it's about time someone implements it. :)

Answer (score -1):

> py-autoreload=1

in the .ini file does the job

Answer (score -2):

```
import gevent.wsgi
import werkzeug.serving

@werkzeug.serving.run_with_reloader
def runServer():
    gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5000), app).serve_forever()
```

(You can use an arbitrary WSGI server)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an answer to my question. I want uwsgi to do the serving. btw: Flask's app.run(debug=True) provides reloading out of the box.

Comment: Although the dev. webserver shipped with Flask provides reloading, it also provides a shell for debugging! You don't want to give a python shell to everyone in production!

Answer (score -3):

I am afraid that Flask is really too bare bones to have an implementation like this bundled by default.

Dynamically reloading code in production is generally a bad thing, but if you are concerned about a dev environment, take a look at this bash shell script http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/watchdir.html

Just change the sleep interval to whatever suits your needs and substitute the echo command with whatever you use to reload uwsgi. I run uwsgi un master mode and just send a killall uwsgi command.