# Django settings.py not updating on production

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a server that is live right now, there is some SMTP stuff I want to change the settings.py of my Django project. I have made the changes, however, I cannot get the server to detect the changes, and it throws a SMTPAuthentication error because the settings.py is still using the old settings.

The server is set up with nginx, and I have tried `service nginx reload` several times, and `apachectl restart` several times. As well as deleting any *.pyc files.

Comment: In production mode (`DEBUG = False`) Django does not reload. Restart the WSGI server (uwsgi, gunicorn…). *Do not run with debug in production!*

Comment: yea, I changed `DEBUG = False`, I can't get it to take effect either, Im not sure how to reload the uwsgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nginx cannot be actually running the site, as it is not a WSGI server. Presumably it is running as a proxy to something like gunicorn or uWSGI; it is those that you need to restart.

Comment: I believe it is uWSGI, how do I restart it?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you started it in the first place. Are you using it under systemd?

Comment: Im not sure, I didn't deploy this app, I am just making a change

Comment: Thinks, `service uwsgi restart` will be work at many *NIX systems

Comment: just reboot the server. It will restart at the start.

Comment: It works. In my case I deployed the site with fabric. fab restart

Answer (score 0):

Autoreload in production is not good idea, but if you understand what you do, you can use additional `python` module for autoreloading or use [additional param for `uwsgi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831748/how-to-set-up-autoreload-with-flaskuwsgi#15864997). Django devel autoreloading not works with `uwsgi`.